# Using Template Defined Variables in Function Calls in C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, tree

I have a function that I am passing in a variable for; the variable, however, is a template variable. I do not know the specifics on how I am supposed to create a function with a template parameter. I do not even know if I am asking the correct question, but when I compile the program, I get the following error in the `main.cpp` file:

```
line 17   error: no matching function for call  to 'BSTree<int>::BSTinsert(TNode<int>&)'
line 49   error note: candidates are: void BSTree<T>::BSTinsert(const T&) [with T = int]
```

I thought that I was doing everything right, but this is the one error that has hindered me from moving on. Any and all help is welcome and appreciated! (I don't think that the other two files -- `treeNode.h` and `treeNode.cpp` -- need to be shown, but I have been wrong before. If they are, lemme know and I will gladly post them. Thank you once again!

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "BSTree.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BSTree<int> bt;
    TNode<int> item;

    for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter value of item: ";
        cin >> item;
        bt.BSTinsert(item); //this is the line with the error
    }

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

BSTree.h:

```
#ifndef BSTREE_H_INCLUDED
#define BSTREE_H_INCLUDED

#include "treeNode.cpp"

template <typename T>
class BSTree
{
    TNode<T> *root;
    void insert(TNode<T> * & r, const T & item);
public:

    BSTree();
    TNode<T>* getRoot();
    void BSTinsert(const T & item);
};

#endif // BSTREE_H_INCLUDED
```

BSTree.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BSTree.h"

template <typename T>
void BSTree<T>::insert(TNode<T> * & r, const T & item)
{
    if(r == NULL)
        TNode<T> newNode = new TNode<T>(item);
    else if(r == item)
        return;

    else if(r->nodeValue > item)
        insert(r->leftChild, item);
    else if(r->nodeValue > item && r->leftChild == NULL)
    {
        TNode<T> newNode = new TNode<T>(item);
        r->leftChild = newNode;
        newNode->parent = r;
    }

    else if(r->nodeValue < item)
        insert(r->rightChild, item);
    else if(r->nodeValue < item && r->rightChild == NULL)
    {
        TNode<T> newNode = new TNode<T>(item);
        r->rightChild = newNode;
        newNode->parent = r;
    }
}

template <typename T>
BSTree<T>::BSTree()
{
    root = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
TNode<T>* BSTree<T>::getRoot()
{
    return root;
}

template <typename T>
void BSTree<T>::BSTinsert(const T& item) //this is the line the note is referring to
{
    TNode<T> tempRoot = getRoot();
    insert(tempRoot, item);
}
```

treeNode.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "treeNode.h"

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
TNode<T>::TNode()
{
    parent = NULL;
    leftChild = NULL;
    rightChild = NULL;
    nodeValue = 0;
}

template <typename T>
TNode<T>::TNode(const T&item, TNode<T> *left, TNode<T> *right, TNode<T> *par)
{
    parent = par;
    leftChild = left;
    rightChild = right;
    nodeValue = item;
}

template <typename T>
void TNode<T>::printNodeInfo()
{
    cout << "Value: " << nodeValue << endl;
    if(parent != NULL)
        cout << "Parent Value: " << parent << endl;
    if(leftChild != NULL)
        cout << "Left Child Value: " << leftChild << endl;
    if(rightChild != NULL)
        cout << "Right Child Value: " << rightChild << endl;
}
```

treeNode.h:

```
#ifndef TREENODE_H_INCLUDED
#define TREENODE_H_INCLUDED

template <typename T>
class TNode
{
public:
    T nodeValue;
    TNode<T> *leftChild, *rightChild, *parent;

    TNode();
    TNode(const T&item, TNode<T> *left = NULL, TNode<T> *right = NULL, TNode<T> *par = NULL);
    void printNodeInfo();

    friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& i, TNode<T>& item ){return i;}
};

#endif // TREENODE_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: `#include "BSTree.cpp"` No no no no no. Implement your template class inline.

Comment: You're calling BSTinsert with a `Node<int>`; you're API requires a plain `int` to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
int main()
{
    BSTree<int> bt;
    int item;

    for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter value of item: ";
        cin >> item;
        bt.BSTinsert(item); //this is the line with the error
    }

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I take away the `TNode<>`, then there are 14 errors, saying this...
`error: invalid conversion from 'TNode<int>*' to 'int'`

Comment: can you give me the line numbers or text corresponding to the errors? also can you add your TNode source?

Comment: All of the errors are not that error, however they are all dealing with an invalid conversion of `int` and `TNode<T>`
All errors are in `BSTree.cpp`
    Lines: 51, 51, 52, 9, 9, 10, 19, 19, 20, 21, 30, 30, 31, 32